# Replace the last number in an int data

Tags: java, replace, int

I have an int like 2213, how i replace the last number 3 to 2 in Java. 
i used the two ways listed below, but is did not work.

```
    int id = 2221;
    String idx = id+"";
    idx = idx.replace("\\d$", 2+"");
    System.out.println(idx);

    StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer(2213+"");
    s1.setCharAt(s1.length() - 1, (char) 8);    
    System.out.print(s1);
```

Comment: (char) 8 is not a printable character AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer id = 2213;

id--;
```

This would be an easy solution. But what's your goal ? Is there any rule you have to implements ? I mean, can we have something more precise than the example only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
int id = 2213;
String idx = ""+id;

StringBuilder mId = new StringBuilder(idx);
mId.setCharAt((mId.length()-1), '2');

System.out.println(mId);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(char) 8` is the character in position 8 in the unicode table, which is not the same as the character `'8'`. If you convert the number to a string you can use string functions to remove and add, or replace the last character:

```
int id = 2221;
String idx = Integer.toString(id);
idx = idx.substring(0, idx.length()-1) + "8";
System.out.println(idx);
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(id);
sb.replace(sb.length()-1, sb.length(), "8");
```

Answer (score -1):

int id = 2221;
    idx = idx.replace("3", "2");

Comment: Can you expand your answer by giving some more details about your solution?